# bower doesn't install backbone-min

Tags: backbone.js, bower

I'm listing "backbone" as a dependency in my bower.json file but when I run `bower install` I get a backbone folder with its own bower.json file (which installs underscore) along with backbone.js, but not backbone-min.js.

I've also tried specifying a version in the bower.json file as such:

```
{
  "name": "backbone",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": null,
    "backbone": "~1.1.0",
    "underscore": null
  }
}
```

So, quite frankly, how I download backbone-min.js with bower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the *backbone-min.js* is part of the list of files for Bower to ignore when installing backbone:

```
{
   "name" : "backbone",
   "version" : "1.1.2",
   "main" : "backbone.js",
   "dependencies" : {
       "underscore" : ">=1.5.0"
   },
   "ignore" : ["backbone-min.js", "docs", "examples", "test", "*.yml", "*.map", ".html", "*.ico"]
}
```

This effects versions 1.1.2 and older. However the master branch includes a new [commit](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/fb55f3824fffe64d768679f42435a61a37e4905c) which sort this issue.
You can change the version of backbone you depend on to "master" to get this change or wait for a new version with this change to be released.